# How to change Owin.AuthenticationIdentityManager's PasswordValidator settings?

Tags: authentication, visual-studio-2013, owin, asp.net-identity

This autogenerated code registers a new user:

```
var manager = new AuthenticationIdentityManager(new IdentityStore());
User u = new User(userName) { UserName = userName };

IdentityResult result = manager.Users.CreateLocalUser(u, Password.Text);
if (result.Success) 
{ ... }
```

How can we change password validation settings?
This is what I've found using dotPeek:
AuthenticationIdentityManager class instance contains UserManager which validates a password using PasswordValidator:
*From class Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager:*

```
result = this.PasswordValidator.Validate(password);

internal IStringValidator PasswordValidator
{
  get
  {
    return this.Manager.Settings.GetIdentityOptions().PasswordValidator;
  }
}
```

*Class Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityOptions:*

```
public IdentityOptions()
{
  this._defaultPasswordValidator = new IdentityOptions.DefaultPasswordValidator(this);
  this._defaultUserNameValidator = new IdentityOptions.DefaultUserNameValidator(this);
  this.MinRequiredPasswordLength = 6;
  this.LocalLoginProvider = "Local";
}

public IStringValidator PasswordValidator
{
  get
  {
    return this._passwordValidator ?? (IStringValidator) this._defaultPasswordValidator;
  }
  set
  {
    this._passwordValidator = value;
  }
}
```

I cannot find where IdentityOptions instance can be accessed or replaced. Is there any example or documentation?

Answer (score 1):

RTM version seems to have dropped AuthenticationIdentityManager. Try upgrading the to latest pre-release version.

In the latest version, you can provide PasswordValidator implementation to UserManager. This will enable customization of password strength validation in your app.

[ASP.NET Identity nighlty packages are now available on MyGet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/09/asp-net-identity-nuget-packages-for-the-nightly-builds-are-available-on-myget.aspx)